# How to get Consumer Key and Consumer Secret while connecting to Quickbooks using Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, quickbooks

I am trying to figure out how do I get the Consumer Key and Consumer Secret from Quickbooks and use it to connect to ADF? ADF connector for QuickBooks asks for Endpoint, Company ID, Consumer Key, Consumer Secret and Refresh Token. I had success in fetching Endpoint, Company ID and Refresh Token. Can someone tell me step by step how do I find Consumer key and Consumer secret?

Answer (score 1):

Intuit uses OAuth 2.0, which means you get a `Client ID` and `Client Secret`.

You should follow the instructions on their site (they include screenshots for each follow-along):

- https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/get-started

Specifically, these instructions:

```
    Development and Production keys can be found in the sidebar on the left. Under Development select Keys and OAuth. 

    Locate your Client ID and Client Secret.
```

If the app is asking for a `Consumer Key` and `Consumer Secret`, then it may be out of date and no longer supported -- consumer keys and secrets are a OAuth v1.0 thing, and Intuit no longer supports OAuth v1.0.

Comment: Sir kindly help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65425821/how-to-turn-on-online-payments-through-quickbooks-api)